# On button click swap JS File thats being loaded using "document.createElement('script')

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get the JS file to swap on click of button.

Below is the code I'm trying to use.
The JS script is loaded in using -

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = http://localhost:8888/test.js
```

On click of buttons at the top I want to be able to change the JS file that is being loaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const script = document.createElement('script');

const areas = 'http://localhost:8888/test.js';
const places = 'http://localhost:8888/test2.js';

$(".link1").click(function () {
    script.src = areas
});
$(".link2").click(function () {
    script.src = places
});
```

https://codepen.io/DCReddish97/pen/EJQgyR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot append "script" to your DOM. Below example using jQuery (you using it anyway):

```js
var $script = $('<script>').attr("type", "text/javascript");
const areas = 'http://localhost:8888/test.js';
const places = 'http://localhost:8888/test2.js';

$('head').append($script);

$(".link1").click(function () {
  $script.attr("src", areas);
});
$(".link2").click(function () {
    $script.attr("src", places);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="link1">LINK 1</button>
<button class="link2">LINK 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try and help, unfortunately this hasn't worked for me, I'm creating a codepen now so you can see roughly what I've got and what I'm trying to achieve.
https://codepen.io/DCReddish97/pen/EJQgyR

Comment: I assumed that you want to change markers on map, when you click on different links. Easiest way to achieve that is to place variables with data into script or use $.ajax call (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax) if content is dynamically generated.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've managed to get the majority functionality now working, but I can't seen to get the other file to hide when button is clicked.
When clicked it's loading in the right js file for the correct button, but I doesn't hide the markers from the js attached to the first selected button.
I've updated the codepen with the $.ajax call I'm now using.

Comment: ID of codepen is changed? Cuz i can't see any changes. EDIT: Before you load new markers, you need to remove old ones: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: Sorry, I was just being stupid and forgot to set the markers to clear. Thanks again for your help.